# how to write a trigger on account to prevent text filed entering name ending with 'text'

Tags: apex, validation

I need to write a trigger on Account which, while inserting a text value as 'someName' ended with 'text' ex: 'renuText' On Account Object it should throw an error. How can I achieve this requirement?

Comment: Why not use a validation rule?

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? There is a community expectation that you will make a good faith effort to solve your problem before asking here.

Comment: I don't really understand how this question is a duplicate of the question indicated.

Answer (score 2):

Something with validation rule having formula as:

```
(RIGHT(Name, 4)) == "text"
```

Comment: I believe it should be equals to text as error should be thrown when value ends with 'text'

Comment: Ah thanks for correction. I always make mistakes from mobile