# Build Validation Account Name ends with a specific text

Tags: validation-rule

I need to build up a validation rule for:
Need to show validation error if Account Name `ends with` a specific text say 'Test'.

How will I achieve this in Salesforce?

Comment: Do you want to make sure the Account name ends with 'Test' or would validating the Name field to make sure the Account name contains 'Test' be enough?

Comment: @TSmith: Account Name should not ends with 'Test'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to write a trigger on account to prevent text filed entering name ending with 'text'](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162071/how-to-write-a-trigger-on-account-to-prevent-text-filed-entering-name-ending-wit)

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/162071/2995

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula could be:

```
(RIGHT(Name, 4)) == "Test"
```